# Why there is no change on my web when I edit css?

Tags: css

I have a weird question. I dont know what is happening but I am working on my web. I am using Filezilla. Css stopped working - no change in code is displaying. I tried to delete all files from Filezilla and upload it again and it was working. After a while it happened again and few times more as I tried the same. I know that the css file I am using is the right one but I dont know why there is no change visible? When I change html it is working but no css. Thanks for your help.

(I am also using subdirectory if there might be some problem?)

Comment: Cache probably...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As panther answered, it is probably because the old css file is loaded from cache instead of the new file. You can bypass this by pressing the ctrl key and f5.

Answer (score 0):

It can be css path mismatch.You can see website console error where explain everything.